# ionic 4 @mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

why code in subscribe run only once?
after execute StartTrack() it run once then nothing happens..
i tried all kind of providers, also shut down battery save and gave app permissions needed.
i check this on two Samsung devices, 8.1 and 9 android version.
anyone had same problem?

```js
this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).then(() => {
      alert("then");
      this.backgroundGeolocation.on(BackgroundGeolocationEvents.location).subscribe(
        (location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
          // this.dataStorage.updateItem("d d",location.latitude,location.longitude,location.time);
          alert("subscribe");
          if (location) {
            this.dataStorage.updateItem("d d", location);
            alert(location.time.toString());
          }
          // this.backgroundGeolocation.finish();
        }
      )
```

Comment: Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.2

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 4 other plugins)

Comment: cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 3.0.3 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"